# Date only updates when app is refreshed SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I want to print the date, however, it states the sam until I refresh the app. this is my code

```
struct Dates: View {
func todayDate() -> String {
    
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
    
    let today = Date() /// Date() is the current date
    let todayAsString = dateFormatter.string(from: today)
    return todayAsString
}

var body: some View {
         Text(todayDate())
```

Would anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: The code is not complete, how do you are refreshing the app/view? The way is coded, the view will never be refreshed.

Comment: It doesn't refresh, that is what im confused about. I don't know how to

Comment: Are you wanting it to constantly update automatically, like a clock would?

Comment: yes exactly, ultimately I want it to update every second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Display Live Time in SwiftUI

You need to create a Timer with the time interval you want to update the Date label. In this case we will update the label every 1 second. First, the ViewModel (the Timer cannot be declared inside the SwiftUI View because it is an struct):

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var currentTime = ""

    var timer = Timer()

    init() {
        let repeatEveryXSeconds: TimeInterval = 1
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: repeatEveryXSeconds, repeats: true, block: { [weak self] timer in
            self?.currentTime = DateFormatter.myFormatter.string(from: Date())
        })
    }
}

extension DateFormatter {
    static let myFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
        return formatter
    }()
}
```

And the view itself:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Date is: \(viewModel.currentTime)")
            .frame(width: 200)
            .padding()
    }
}
```

You can use also CalendarUserNotifications triggers: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/scheduling_a_notification_locally_from_your_app

Comment: The `DateFormatter` should probably be cached and not created on every iteration as they are famously expensive to create

Comment: @jnpdx Good apreciation! I updated the code.